# Sensors name and vendor Android

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

Is it possible display only the `sensor name` and the `vendor` from this?

```
public class SensorikTestActivity extends Activity {

private ListView listView;
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private List<Sensor> deviceSensors = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    listView = ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1));

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    deviceSensors = mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Sensor>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, deviceSensors));
}
}
```

actually it displays all information of sensors but i need only a few info. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No built-in approach. You need to do some coding.

Create custom object like `SensorDetails` with only attributes you want (name, vendor etc.,).

Instead of `List<Sensor> deviceSensors` create `List<YourCustomClass>`. Populate your custom object with values from `Sensor` List and set it to Adapter.

Comment: I thought it was possible extract only what i need from this code :-(

Comment: @David_D: AFAIK, no. Let us wait and see if any one has other solutions.

Comment: i hope ahaha. because your solution maybe it's a bit too much for me :)